# Getting raw data when attempting to retrieve Edittext input with a view model

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-viewmodel, android-binder

I am trying to build a multi page form for an application. As per suggestions here I am attempting to use a ViewModel to store the data input by the user to easily get it in another fragment, and to update the edittext to their previous input if they navigate back and forth. As well the application must have view binding.

However, when attempting to retrieve the input in a toast message in the last fragment or put it in the edittext, I get this as an output
"androidx.lifecycle.MutableLiveData@8177d2c"

Why is this happening? I am using .toString() methods with getText() so I don't know why

My code:

**SharedViewModel.java**

```
package com.loopbreakr.viewmodelform;

import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModel;
import androidx.lifecycle.MutableLiveData;

public class SharedViewModel extends ViewModel {
    private MutableLiveData<CharSequence> answerOneText = new MutableLiveData<>();
    private MutableLiveData<CharSequence> answerTwoText = new MutableLiveData<>();
    private MutableLiveData<CharSequence> answerThreeText =  new MutableLiveData<>();

    public void setAnswerOneText(CharSequence input) {
        answerOneText.setValue(input);
    }

    public void setAnswerTwoText(CharSequence input) {
        answerTwoText.setValue(input);
    }

    public void setAnswerThreeText(CharSequence input){
        answerThreeText.setValue(input);
    }

    public MutableLiveData<CharSequence> getAnswerOneText() {
        return answerOneText;
    }

    public MutableLiveData<CharSequence> getAnswerTwoText() {
        return answerTwoText;
    }

    public MutableLiveData<CharSequence> getAnswerThreeText() {
        return answerThreeText;
    }
}
```

MainActivity.java

```
package com.loopbreakr.viewmodelform;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.navigation.NavController;
import androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        NavHostFragment navHostFragment = (NavHostFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.nav_host_fragment);
        NavController navController = navHostFragment.getNavController();
    }
}
```

**PageOne.java fragment that I am trying to retrieve data from**

```
package com.loopbreakr.viewmodelform;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.databinding.DataBindingUtil;
import androidx.databinding.ViewDataBinding;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import androidx.lifecycle.Observer;
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider;
import androidx.navigation.NavController;
import androidx.navigation.Navigation;

import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.EditText;

import com.loopbreakr.viewmodelform.databinding.FragmentPageOneBinding;


public class PageOne extends Fragment {
    private SharedViewModel sharedViewModel;
    private FragmentPageOneBinding binding = null;


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        ViewDataBinding fragmentBinding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(inflater, R.layout.fragment_page_one,container,false);
        binding = (FragmentPageOneBinding) fragmentBinding;
        return  binding.getRoot();
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

        sharedViewModel = new ViewModelProvider(requireActivity()).get(SharedViewModel.class);
        if(binding != null){
            binding.pageOneInput.setText(sharedViewModel.getAnswerOneText().toString());
            binding.nextToTwo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    sharedViewModel.setAnswerOneText(binding.pageOneInput.getText().toString());
                    goNext();
                }
            });
            binding.returnButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    goBack();
                }
            });
        }
    }

    public void goNext() {
        NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(getView());
        navController.navigate(R.id.action_pageOne_to_pageTwo);
    }
    public void goBack(){
        NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(getView());
        navController.navigate((R.id.action_pageOne_to_description));
    }

}
```

**Last fragment PageThree.java where I attempt to get the data and display it as a toast message**

```
package com.loopbreakr.viewmodelform;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.databinding.DataBindingUtil;
import androidx.databinding.ViewDataBinding;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import androidx.lifecycle.Observer;
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider;
import androidx.navigation.NavController;
import androidx.navigation.Navigation;

import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.EditText;

import com.loopbreakr.viewmodelform.databinding.FragmentPageOneBinding;


public class PageOne extends Fragment {
    private SharedViewModel sharedViewModel;
    private FragmentPageOneBinding binding = null;


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        ViewDataBinding fragmentBinding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(inflater, R.layout.fragment_page_one,container,false);
        binding = (FragmentPageOneBinding) fragmentBinding;
        return  binding.getRoot();
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

        sharedViewModel = new ViewModelProvider(requireActivity()).get(SharedViewModel.class);
        if(binding != null){
            binding.pageOneInput.setText(sharedViewModel.getAnswerOneText().toString());
            binding.nextToTwo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    sharedViewModel.setAnswerOneText(binding.pageOneInput.getText().toString());
                    goNext();
                }
            });
            binding.returnButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    goBack();
                }
            });
        }
    }

    public void goNext() {
        NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(getView());
        navController.navigate(R.id.action_pageOne_to_pageTwo);
    }
    public void goBack(){
        NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(getView());
        navController.navigate((R.id.action_pageOne_to_description));
    }

}
```

Also, here are the XMLs incase they are relevant

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
        android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:defaultNavHost="true"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:navGraph="@navigation/nav_graph" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

fragment_page_one.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout>
    <data>
        <variable
            name="viewModel"
            type="com.loopbreakr.viewmodelform.SharedViewModel"/>

    </data>
    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".PageOne">

    <!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="@string/hello_blank_fragment" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/nextToTwo"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="next"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/returnButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Return"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

    <MultiAutoCompleteTextView
        android:id="@+id/pageOneInput"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textAutoCorrect|textMultiLine"
        android:maxLines="4"
        android:minLines="4"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/textView2"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</layout>
```

Answer (score 0):

override the toString method in model class it will work

```
 @Override
public String toString() {
    return "BeanDetails{" +
            "sl_no='" + sl_no + '\'' +
            ", type='" + type + '\'' +
            ", count='" + count + '\'' +
            ", percent='" + percent + '\'' +
            '}';
}
```

in my model class there is four variable so that is why it is showing 4 variable inside the beandetails